# Where to place my own public classes

Tags: symfony

I have many bundles in my project and I want to write some classes that use in all of the bundles.
where should I place my own classes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to create a generic bundle "CoreBundle" that will contain all shared classes like Entities, Repositories, Managers, Services, shared Form and views...

Then you'll be able to use classes inside your application bundles. If a class is specific to just one bundle, add it in this bundle and not inside the CoreBundle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
But I didn't get My answer. 

For example, I Have a permission class that check every permission in website,
Can I place this class in services ? or another places ?